# MVC 3 Client Side Validation Catches Some ValidationAttributes but not others?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm confused by this behavior:

I have an out-of-the-box MVC3 app. I haven't really done any customization from the what the scaffolding template gives me.

In web.config, clientsidevalidationenabled and unobtrusivevalidation are both true.

I have a class with one field using the **Required** annotation, one using **StringLength** and one using **RegularExpression**. When I'm editing an object, the textboxes for the properties marked with StringLength & Regex report problems instantly in the UI, but the textbox for the Required doesn't.

If I hit SAVE, then "Model.IsValid" is the controller sess the problem with the missing Required and I get the UI error message next to the text box.

If I view the source of the page, I can see that the markup for the required property does have the dataval-req and other related attributes generated by the Unobtrusive validation.

Is this expected behavior? If it is, what's the reason? If it's not, what might I be doing wrong?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Is the page posting to the action in the controller even with the fields not filled out?

What happens when you type in a required field, tab to another field, go back and remove the original fields contents?

Comment: @Beavis ... responding below under your answer... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gotten to the bottom of this behavior, just by banging on the keyboard some more. It's as expected. In the Create view, the behavior is as @Beavis describes. In the edit view, unobtrusive validation prevents the required property from being validated on tabbing BEFORE the first attempt at hitting SAVE. SAVE then does a UI validation  (no postback occurs) and shows the error message next to the property. Once I've hit save that first time, that property responds to tabbing. So now if I make it valid, the message disappears on tab. If I erase the contents of the text box, the message reappears on tab.

Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: I guess one 'hack' around this would be to use a >1 string length as well? Good to know the interesting behavior here.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the page is not posting back to the server, this should be the correct behavior. The required client-validation will fire only if:

1. You don't enter data and try to post to the server.
2. You enter data in the text box and then remove it.

Otherwise the user would be inundated with error messages.

Comment: ahhh... I get #2 in a create view so that's really useful info, thanks. Funny that I can't get it to happen at all on an Edit view where I started out with valid data and deleted it. What should I expect in an edit view? Just #1 only...no matter what?

Comment: @JulieLerman good question.  Unfortunately I don't have VS in front of me to try.  I would expect a required field to trip the same way on edit.  Did you try removing the data and then tabbing to another field?

Comment: I did that and a variety of other things to move in and out of the field. Even tried backspacing vs. highlight and delete. Oddddddd. ;)